# Prime generator too slow

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that looks for the next prime and adds it to a list on a txt file. However this program is still slower than the one I did in python. I would like to make it faster. I don't know if instead of constantly reading the file a dynamic memory would help. If so, could you please help me implement one correctly.
Any other improvement is also welcome as i am learning

```cs
int root = 0, num = 0, p;
FILE *f;

int check_if_prime(){
    //calculates root to prevent calculating it at each step
    root = sqrt(p);
    //starts at the beginning of the file
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    //checks if p is prime
    num = 0;
    while (num <= root){
        fscanf(f, "%d", &num);
        if (p % num == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    f = fopen("PATH", "a+");

    //prints all the numbers
    int last = 0;
    while (1){
        fscanf(f, "%d", &num);
        if (num == last) break;
        printf("\n %d", num);
        last = num;
    }

    //asks up to which number the program should calculate the primes
    int nmax;
    printf("\nnmax: ");
    scanf("%d", &nmax);

    //checks through the integers for primes and adds the to the file if they are
    for(int p = last + 2; p < nmax; p += 2){
        if (check_if_prime(p, f)){
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
            fprintf(f, "%d\n", p);
        }
    }

    //ends and restarts the program
    printf("\nPress 1 and enter\n\n\n");
    scanf("%d");
    fclose(f);
    main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not ignore results from IO operations. Any one of them could fail which is completely out of your control.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make a program that looks for the next prime and adds it to a list on a txt file.

Your program seems to be trying to find *all* primes up to a user-entered maximum, given an input list of primes.  One relatively simple approach to this would be to implement a prime number sieve, such as the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  If you can assume that the input file does not omit any primes within the range it covers, then you can use its contents (at least those not exceeding `sqrt(nmax)`) to partially or wholly initialize the sieve.  You will want to allocate memory dynamically for the sieve itself.

This will be more efficient than performing an independent primality test (of any useful kind) on every candidate in the target range.  Inasmuch as you are inherently limiting yourself to numbers representable by type `int`, the amount of available memory is probably not a limiting factor, at least for a general-purpose desktop, laptop, or server machine.

As far as I/O goes, you have to read the whole file once, and you have to write each new prime you find.  There is no getting around that.  But don't do any more I/O than you need to do.  In particular you should not need to read the file more than once, and having read it to its end, you should not need to seek around in it before writing.  It would, however, make sense to defer the reading until after you input `nmax` and allocate your sieve array, integrating it with your sieve implementation.

Note that if you wanted to find only the single next prime, then a different approach might be more sensible.